# How do you nest fixed effects in asreml-R?

Tags: nested-data, asreml

I have 4 geographic populations which are nested within 2 population types (sympatry vs allopatry). Geographic population 1 and 2 is nested in population type 1 (allopatry), geographic population 3 and 4 are nested in population type 2 (sympatry). I am curious as to how I would assign this nesting to these fixed effects (geographic population, population type).
Is it just:

```
poptype  +  geopop:poptype
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you want:

```
library(tibble)
dat <- tribble(
  ~ geopop, ~ type, ~ y,
  "P1", "Allo", 1,
  "P1", "Allo", 1.5,
  "P2", "Allo", 2,
  "P3", "Sym",  3,
  "P4", "Sym",  3.25)
dat <- transform(dat, geopop=factor(geopop), type=factor(type))
library(asreml)

m1 <- asreml(y ~ type + geopop:type, data=dat)
wald(m1)
Wald tests for fixed effects.
Response: y
Terms added sequentially; adjusted for those above.

              Df Sum of Sq Wald statistic Pr(Chisq)    
(Intercept)    1   23.1125         184.90 < 2.2e-16 ***
type           1    3.1688          25.35 4.782e-07 ***
geopop:type    2    0.4063           3.25    0.1969    
residual (MS)       0.1250                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```